# How to consume web service via GET methods?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a normal 3rd party SOAP service with WSDL and stuff. The problem is - it only accepts GET requests. How can I access it in c#?

When I add that service to VS via `Add Service Reference` and try to use it as usual:

```
var service = new BaseSvcClient(
                 new BasicHttpContextBinding(), 
                 new EndpointAddress("http://some.internal.ip/WebServices/Base.svc"));
var ver = service.Version();
```

I see (via fiddler) that it actually sends POST requests and web-service responds with `Endpoint not found` error message.
If I simply hit `http://some.internal.ip/WebServices/Base.svc/Version` in a browser the proper xml is returned.

I can use WebClient, but then I have to construct all the GET requests manually, which doesn't look good.
Are there other solutions?

Comment: After you add it as usual, take a good look at the generated config. Your config-by-code relies on all defaults. I think you're missing a behavior or two.

Comment: weid to me, service public as SOAP, how can you access by REST?

Comment: unfortunately after adding a service (References->right click->Add service reference) I have nothing added to my app.config (it's just <configuration></configuration>, so don't know where to take missing behaviors from

Comment: @Cuong probably it's something like wcf service with `WebInvoke` attributes and `UriTemplate`s but don't know exactly

Comment: Yes, there's a WSDL available at `/Base.svc?wsdl` and even a help page at `Base.svc/help` which lists the actions with their urls and methods like: `Version GET Base.svc/Version; Echo GET Base.svc/Echo?value={VALUE}` etc

Answer (score 1):

I have found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12517479/291695) that helped me a lot.
Basically if I take an autogenerated interface for the client, decorate methods with `[WebGet]` and use

```
var cf = new WebChannelFactory<IBaseSvc2>(new Uri("..."));
var service = cf.CreateChannel();
var result = service.Version();
```

it all works well. That's not a perfect solution, since changes won't be picked up automatically, so may be there are other solutions?

P.S. an interface for a web service is now like:

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName = "BaseService.IBaseSvc")]
    public interface IBaseSvc2
    {
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IBaseSvc/Version", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IBaseSvc/VersionResponse")]
        [WebGet]
        VersionInformation Version();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by adding the protocols in config file

```
<webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Comment: This would allow POST methods, and should be done on server-side, yes? But I have no access to that service configuration, I have to consume GET's..